# Assuming Wave Function Collapse Actually Exists, Can a Wavefunction Collapse into Another Wavefunction that is not the Delta Function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, measurements, wavefunction-collapse

Suppose we have a time independent potential and suppose $\psi_1(x)$ and $\psi_2(x)$ are two stationary states of the potential with energies $E_1$ and $E_2$. Suppose the wavefunction is
$$
\Psi(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg(\psi_1 e^{-iE_1 t/\hbar} + \psi_2 e^{-iE_2 t/\hbar}\bigg)
$$

**Scenario 1:** Suppose at a particular time $t_0$ I measure the position. The theoretical probability I get a position between $a$ and $b$ is
$$
\int_a^b |\Psi(x,t_0)|^2 dx
$$

**Scenario 2:** Suppose at a time $t < t_0$ I measure the energy and obtain $E_1$. Then suppose at time $t_0$ I measure the position. What would be the theoretical probability that I get a position between $a$ and $b$? Will it be
$$
\int_a^b |\Psi(x,t_0)|^2 dx
$$
once again, or will it be

$$
\int_a^b |\psi_1(x)|^2 dx?
$$

Comment: "Can a Wavefunction Collapse into Another Wavefunction that is not the Delta Function?" Answer: Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_interpretation#Principles), measuring energy $E_1$ can be thought of as a projection/collapse of your initial superposition state onto the energy eigenstate $\psi_1$, caused by the measurement.

So if you measure eigenvalue $E_1$ at $t<t_0$, then your results for measurements at $t\geq t_0$ will be given by

$$\int^b_a |\psi_1(x)|^2dx.$$

The collapse occurs to one of the eigenstates of the operator associated with the property that you are measuring. If you are measuring energy, your state will be projected onto an energy eigenstate. If you measure spin, your system is projected onto a spin eigenstate and if you measure position your system is projected onto a position eigenstate. The projection to a dirac delta function is thus associated with the "spectrum" of the  position operator and measurements of the position of a particle.

Comment: Thank you very much.